# What does this annotation in Intellij source code mean?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When looking into the source code of *IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition* project in github, in one of the files I found the following notation:

```
void m() {
    <selection><caret>System.out.println("");</selection>
}
```

What does this `<selection>` annotation mean? By which tool is it being processed?

The complete source of [afterEnumConstantWithArgs.java](https://github.com/rtyley/intellij-community-set-committer-to-author/blob/master/java/java-tests/testData/codeInsight/daemonCodeAnalyzer/quickFix/copyAbstractMethodImplementation/afterEnumConstantWithArgs.java) is as follows.

```
// "Use existing implementation of 'm'" "true"
enum I {
    A("a") {
        void m() {
            <selection><caret>System.out.println("");</selection>
        }
    },
    B("b") {
        public void m() {
            System.out.println("");
        }
    };
    abstract void m();
    I(String s){}
}
```

Comment: Which file? Can you link to it?

Comment: Done @DarthAndroid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly you should note you're reading test *data*, not a source file itself. Presumably this is emulating a file that would be loaded into IntelliJ.

<caret> would be referring to where the caret is in the file, i.e. the blinking cursor. <selection> would be the code that's currently selected, which is why it has a beginning and end tag.

Source: reading the code until I figured this out.

Seems to be parsed by [this file](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/openapi/fileEditor/impl/text/TextEditorProvider.java#L66).